# Is there a way to allow a file to automatically grow in Azure File Storage API

Tags: azure, azure-storage

The Azure file storage API seems fine if you know how big the file is going to be but otherwise it seems to throw errors if you try to write beyond the end of the file.

I have opened a share and created a folder and would like to now append data to a file. I don't know quite how long the file will end up but if you try to open a file you have to specify the size. I could I suppose guess the maximum likely size and resize downwards afterwards or I could try to write my own stream that tracks when the write position extends beyond the current length and then sets the length of the file before the buffer is flushed to the stream of the open file but is this necessary? Is there some simple way to write and append to a file without knowing upfront the eventual size of the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do take a look at [`Append Blobs`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2015/04/13/introducing-azure-storage-append-blob.aspx). I believe they would fit your requirement perfectly. All the new content gets appended to the existing blob contents and you don't have to do anything regarding this.

Comment: Thanks Guarav, actually I might not be able personally to use your suggestions as it requires the latest API and we have some stuff reliant on the old API. The less than perfect solution I'm looking at is to use an in memory stream because the file is about 9Mb in total so that is not too heavy and then I know the final file size upfront. However it does appear you cannot simply append to a file storage file easily and you have to resize first.